# Load error with Susy - Sass - Compass - watch

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, susy-compass, compass-sass

I have compass 1.0.0.alpha.18 installed with Sass 3.3.2 and Susy 2.0.0 and get

"Loaderror on line["45"] of C: cannot load such file --wdm"

The process that I am trying in the console is this:

```
gem install sass

gem install compass
```

When I do this, it tells me "successfully installed compass-0.12.3 but if I run compass --version I get Compass 1.0.0.alpha.18.

```
gem install susy

compass watch [my sass folder]
```

Returns: Compass is watching for changes
overwrite ../css/styles.css
Loaderror on line["45"] of C: cannot load such file --wdm

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the relevant [issue on github](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1470). For this kind of error, it's always a good idea to check the bug tracker. Cheers!

Comment: After banging my head into the wall, rolling back to different version of ruby, downloading the devkit as per your link. I now get "Syntax error: Incompatible units: 'em' and 'rem'" errors when I call @include susy-grid-background; Ready to give up - not a ruby developer so maybe this is too much for me.

Comment: You're actually out of ruby territory now, and dealing with an error in your code. I hope things get easier for you. I'm not a ruby developer either, and I've survived so far. The new error you are seeing is probably caused by setting a mix of `em` and `rem` values in your Susy settings. All those settings should use the same units. If you paste your settings, I can tell you for certain. I wrote Susy, so I know my way around it fairly well. Cheers,